# Issue with ping sweep that reads in an IP address

Tags: bash

The main issue I am having with this is pinging the read in IP address. It always says that the address is down.

```
Ping_Sweep()
{
echo -e '\n'
echo  '----- Ping Sweep -----'
echo -e '\n'
command date >>  pingresults.tx
echo "Enter in the first three number sequences of an IP address (ex. ###.###.###): "
read -r ip_address
for x in $ip_address
do
    echo "IP address being pinged: $ip_address"
    if ping –c 1 "$x" &> /dev/null 
    then
        echo "IP: $x is up."
    else  
        echo "Ping failed. $x is down."
    fi
done
Main_Menu
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ping –c` should be `ping -c`. Your original command has an en dash. This is usually caused by copying code rendered by a bad blog framework.

Comment: Thx that fixed the issue